# Alternate to ORDER BY subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-order-by

From the database at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_orderby2, for example (Click "Run SQL"), I want to list the customer who has the largest CustomerID that is greater than 80 first among a list of all customers from USA.  So I use

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country = 'USA'
ORDER BY CustomerID = (SELECT MAX(CustomerID) FROM Customers 
    WHERE CustomerID > 80 AND Country = 'USA') DESC, PostalCode;
```

but this is not the real query I'm using.  If the SELECT... FROM... WHERE... portion of the query is more complex, what is a more elegant query?

The actual query I am trying to modify is

```
SELECT post.postid, post.visible, post.userid, post.parentid, post.vote_count
FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "post AS post
WHERE post.threadid = $threadid
AND post.visible IN (1" . (!empty($deljoin) ? ", 2" : "") . 
    ($show['approvepost'] ? ", 0" : "") . ")
ORDER BY post.postid = {$threadinfo['firstpostid']} DESC, post.vote_count > 5 DESC, 
    post.dateline $postorder
```

where the `post.vote_count > 5 DESC` portion I am trying to replace with only the largest post.vote_count that is larger than 5.  So I use:

```
SELECT post.postid, post.visible, post.userid, post.parentid, post.vote_count
FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "post AS post
WHERE post.threadid = $threadid
AND post.visible IN (1" . (!empty($deljoin) ? ", 2" : "") . 
    ($show['approvepost'] ? ", 0" : "") . ")
ORDER BY post.postid = {$threadinfo['firstpostid']} DESC, post.vote_count = (
    SELECT MAX(post.vote_count)
    FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "post AS post
    WHERE post.threadid = $threadid
    AND post.visible IN (1" . (!empty($deljoin) ? ", 2" : "") . 
        ($show['approvepost'] ? ", 0" : "") . ")
    AND post.vote_count > 5
)
DESC, post.dateline $postorder
```

and all is good.  But you can imagine a more complex query, perhaps with INNER JOIN, whose SELECT... FROM... WHERE... etc. must all be duplicated in the subquery.

So my question is, I suspect, can you order query results so the first item (*within those results*) has the maximum of a field, and the remainder ordered otherwise, without essentially rewriting the entire query in a subquery?

Comment: How large is your database? The query isn't overly complex, it's strange that it should take a long time. Could you run an `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: @Benoit Garret Good point.  I've hopefully elucidated my question.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support CTE's, which would have been the perfect solution to simplify your query. They can be emulated with a view though :

```
CREATE VIEW c AS (SELECT Customer.* FROM Customer WHERE Country = "USA");
SELECT c.* FROM c ORDER BY CustomerID = (SELECT MAX(CustomerID) FROM c) DESC;
DROP VIEW c;
```

In your case, this would give :

```
CREATE VIEW p AS (
    SELECT post.postid, post.visible, post.userid, post.parentid, post.vote_count
    FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "post AS post
    WHERE post.threadid = $threadid
    AND post.visible IN (1" . (!empty($deljoin) ? ", 2" : "") . 
        ($show['approvepost'] ? ", 0" : "") . ")
);
SELECT p.* FROM p
ORDER BY p.postid = {$threadinfo['firstpostid']} DESC, p.vote_count = (
    SELECT MAX(p.vote_count)
    FROM p
    WHERE p.vote_count > 5
)
DESC, post.dateline $postorder;
DROP VIEW p;
```

Answer (score -2):

This query will list  data in descending order of CustomerID

```
 SELECT * FROM Customers
    WHERE Country = 'USA'
    ORDER BY CustomerID  DESC, PostalCode;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was about listing with a filter, and inserting this in another query.